# How do I add extra info in the title of a Cocoa OSX Document Application

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I want it to show the File Icon in the header, as well as file name like a normal document application, but then I also want to display the page number, similar to how Preview does it. Terminal also does this but it show additional info like size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to accomplish.

The `NSWindow` object has a `title` property, that you can modify.

Each time the user loads a document or scrolls to a different page, you need to update the title accordingly.

```
documentWindow = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@ - Page x of y", document.displayName];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NSWindowController subclass override `windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:`. When the page changes, call `synchronizeWindowTitleWithDocumentName`.